# Jquery datatables string filters

Tags: jquery, datatables

Below code works just fine and gets ALL the data. I would like to insert some filter strings on the datatable(sample_container). So for a given sample_app, would like to filter automatically with some filter strings(filter1, filter2) for sample_container datatable when the page loads. Any ideas?

```
 $("#sample_container").html("<h2>Sample libs</h2>");
 $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "some_url",
            data: some_data,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain: true,
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {
                $("#sample_container").html("<h2>Sample Libraries</h2>");
                html = "<table class='datatable'>";
                blah blah
                }
                html += "</table>";
                $("#sample_container").append(html);
                $("#sample_container .datatable").dataTable({ "bPaginate": false,
                                                           "bAutoWidth": false,
                                                           "bFilter": false,
                                                           "bInfo": false
                }).columnFilter({ sPlaceHolder: "head:after",
                                  aoColumns: [ { type: "text" },
                                               { type: "text" },
                                               { type: "text" }
                                  ]
                });
            },

        });


 {% if sample_app %}
    <h1>{{ sample_app.id }}  - {{ sample_app.name }}</h1>
    <br/>
    blah blah...
 {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not only is it faster, but more direct to just do a server-side implementation of DataTables.  Essentially, you're drawing an entire table to the dom, then completely re-writing it over.....which is very inefficient and likely can't handle more than a few hundred rows of data before becoming clunky.

Datatables, done via "Server Side" query:

```
$('#marketinghistory').dataTable( {     
            "bDestroy":true,
            "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]], 
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "url of ajax source",
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "bFilter":false,
            "bLengthChange": true,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bSort": true,
            "iDisplayLength": 15,
            "bInfo": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                  { "sTitle": "column title", "sWidth": "5%", "sClass":"center" },
                  { "sTitle": "column title", "sWidth": "25%" , "sClass":"center"},
                  { "sTitle": "column title", "sWidth": "10%", "sClass":"center" },
                  { "sTitle": "column title", "sWidth": "5%", "sClass":"center" }
            ]
        });
```

Now, for filtering, you've got a few options.  If you know what you're going to do ahead of time, you could just pass them as variables in the "data" field and do your sort at the server.  But, you might want it to be variable....in which case there's a few more hoops.

Adding this code block to the datatables code above will allow you to do variable filters:

```
"fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
                var name = $('#namesearch').val();
                var phone = $('#phonesearch').val();
                var company = $('#companysearch').val();

                aoData.push({ "name": "name", "value": name },
                            { "name": "phone", "value": phone },
                            { "name": "company", "value": company }
                );

                $.ajax( {
                        "dataType": 'json',
                        "type": "POST",
                        "url": sSource,
                        "data": aoData,
                        "success": fnCallback
                } );
            }
```

So, the variables are set to values of input fields on a page that could be used to filter based on user input.  aodata.push sets up the data to push back in the callback, and the ajax callback does the work.  I use this pattern on advanced search pages with search fields on the left and a datatable on the right.  Initially, with blank fields there is no search filter, but as values are filled in and the table is redrawn, the server can filter down the query.

Of course, this requires a fairly straightforward back-end setup to facilitate the query.  A [tut on that is here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html).